# How to make my default gateway permanent in CentOS? So that after a reboot it does not get lost

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I have a CentOS running. It is important to have my CentOS available when I am remotely connected to a VPN router. I tried to add a default gateway to the VPN router, but after reboot it goes away. How can i put this as permanent?

```
ip route add 192.168.2.3 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i've read your question right, i think you want to add

`GATEWAY=192.168.2.3`

into /etc/sysconfig/network then reboot or do `service network restart` to test it.

Although i'm not entirely sure from your question that you do actually want a default gateway at all. I think you may just want to make a static route permanent ?

Comment: I want to make 192.168.2.1/24 subnet route permanent.

Comment: ok. add a route-eth0 file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts, as outlined here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/permanent-static-routes-on-centos-red-hat-enterprise-linux-565828/

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is running CentOS with multiple NICs, only 1 is connected to the Internet and you want to make that particular interface to take all the Internet traffic, then add following line in to your `/etc/sysconfig/network` file:

```
GATEWAYDEV=network_interface
GATEWAY=default_gateway_ip
```

Save and restart your network services. This worked for me and nothing else was working.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to add that line to the appropriate /etc/ifconfig.INT (where "INT" represents the appropriate interface), just like we do with dhclient sometimes (notice the leading explanation point inserted as the first character):

```
!ip route add 192.168.2.3 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
```

(I haven't tried CentOS, but I'm assuming this mechanism should essentially be the same as it is on NetBSD.)

Answer (score 0):

Just realized, to add below to the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-your_interface_name doesn't work, must be on the ifcfg file:

```
default via x.x.x.x dev y
```