# On my centos linux box the ip address and default gateway are reset each night?

Tags: centos

Hi I've tried quite a few things to do with config files like from here

[How to make my default gateway permanent in CentOS? So that after a reboot it does not get lost](https://superuser.com/questions/320821/how-to-make-my-default-gateway-permanent-in-centos-so-that-after-a-reboot-it-do)

and here

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/permanent-static-routes-on-centos-red-hat-enterprise-linux-565828/

In fact I've just done that second one so that might have solved the problem.

But I'm non the wiser on how this even happens - I do top and the box has been on for many days.

I did solve a problem with resolve.conf with dhcp and think that this problem might be related.

What's odd is that this has been like this for 2 weeks but the people who control the network say that it's nothing to do with them and we don't change many things on the server aside from yumming a couple of programs.

So if anyone knows either

a) What could be doing it

b) Other things to check

We do have webmin and only command line on the system so anything that I could check in either of them would be helpful.

Thanks
Richard

Comment: Hi is there any ideas here at all - I've been trying disabling DHCP and still no help. If anyone could help it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Just popped in a cron to do it each morning before people start for work job done!
Fingers crossed!
Richard

Comment: Yeah thought this would work - but nope - in the root crontab as well